# I can't get the GPS to work

Tags: windows-phone-7, geolocation, gps

I'm using the class in this page to get the current location coordinates on my Windows Phone: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/134982/A-helper-class-to-get-the-current-location-on-a-Wi

I don't know why I always get "Unknown" location. I've tried simpler ways to get the location but haven't succeded.
My GPS is working because I loas Maps appand walk, and I can see the spot moving correctly.
I've checked the GeoCoordinateWatcher.Permisson property and its value is "Granted". I already have this line `<Capability Name="ID_CAP_LOCATION"/>` in WMAppManifest.xml.

What I don't understand of the code in the address I've given above are this lines:

```
var immediate = new ImmediateLocation(x => location = x);
immediate.GetLocation();

GeoCoordinate location;
```

Why is it declaring location after using it? I declare it before. Is there something I should know?

[EDIT]

Now I've understood the lambda expression I get two exceptions:

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in System.Device.dll
A first chance exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
```

This is the StackTrace

```
en System.Device.Location.GeoCoordinateWatcher.<>c__DisplayClass6.<OnPositionStatusChanged>b__4(Object _)
en System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(RuntimeMethodInfo rtmi, Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isBinderDefault, Assembly caller, Boolean verifyAccess, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
en System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
en System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
en System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeOne(Object[] args)
en System.MulticastDelegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
en System.Delegate.DynamicInvoke(Object[] args)
en System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
en System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Dispatch(DispatcherPriority priority)
en System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.OnInvoke(Object context)
en System.Windows.Hosting.CallbackCookie.Invoke(Object[] args)
en System.Windows.Hosting.DelegateWrapper.InternalInvoke(Object[] args)
en System.Windows.RuntimeHost.ManagedHost.InvokeDelegate(IntPtr pHandle, Int32 nParamCount, ScriptParam[] pParams, ScriptParam& pResult)
```

I've found this, I'm not sure it's related to my case, but if it helps someone to help me...

http://onebusawaywp7.codeplex.com/workitem/14695

Comment: How do u know it is not working? I say this because you usually should have some UI trigger when location changes (in the action you are giving to the ctor)

Comment: I'll go and find how actions work. If then I still don't know how to solve the issue I'll post it here. If anybody knows any link that could help me in this issue please share :)

Comment: I've edited the post, with my actual problems

Comment: The line giving me errors is this one: _watcher.StatusChanged -= new EventHandler<GeoPositionStatusChangedEventArgs>(_watcher_StatusChanged); If I comment it out, then I can handle the NullReferenceException and everything works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You supply an Action parameter to the ImmediateLocation constructor. Go and study something about lambda expressions - then you'll see that the location is not being used prior to its declaration.

As far the "Unknown" location is concerned, nobody can answer without knowing anything about the ImmediateLocation class. For example take the one published [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/134982/A-helper-class-to-get-the-current-location-on-a-Wi/?display=Mobile): After you call GetLocation, the location gets filled asynchronously, i.e. sometimes in the future. If you test the value immediately, then you MUST fail. In my opinion that class is simply wrongly designed.

Comment: I've posted the link with the class. The link you provided shows exactly the same as the page I've posted.
I'm sorry to bother you with my lack of knowledge, I'm just starting. But if I declare the location after that line, Visual Studio complains. But thank you for telling me what is that expression because I hadn't seen it before. I tried to search how that worked but without any clue I couldn't find it